# Ally Bank zero commission vs Robinhood no commission fees?

Tags: united-states, fees, online-brokerage, robinhood

Ally Bank claims to have zero-commission transaction fees accounts for trading, Robinhood does the same. Do they both actually not charge any fees/commissions? My understanding was that the free fees model was only Robinhood's?

Comment: After Schwab announced $0 commission a couple weeks ago a number of other brokers joined the race to the bottom.  You still pay some exchange fee of some number of pennies per trade.  At this point I'm not sure why anyone would use Robinhood.

Comment: This round of commission cutting was set off by Interactive Brokers

Comment: @quid I've said this before and I'll say it again - to compete, Robinhood needs to step up and *pay* people to trade (by kicking back some of the order flow payment to their customers)

Comment: @Michael - The routing fees in question are sub penny.  One of their 4 largest routing recipients was Citadel and they paid RH about 25 basis points per share last year (less than 25 cents per round lot).  So if RH shares some of that with you, you're not going to see much of a kickback.  With major discount brokers eliminating commissions, I don't see how RH's stripped down platform and inferior services can compete, kickback or not.

Answer (score 2):

Interactive Brokers introduced IBKR LITE (no commissions) which was then followed by Schwab, Ameritrade, E*Trade and then Ally.

Be aware that free doesn't always mean best price.  Robinhood makes a sizable portion of their revenue from Payment For Order Flow which is effectively routing customer orders to high-frequency traders in exchange for a fee.  This can  result in a  delayed fill and a poorer price. Paying a few extra dollars here or there for a trade is probably meaningless to an investor but it's significant for a trader.

Comment: yes paying few dollars for trade is meaningless for investor, but then how to find best broker, When i look at marketing of Fidelity they claim, better money market and faster execution. Vanguard has better sweep account, but to sell naked put, one has to make phone call( very time consuming)

Comment: Fidelity and  Vanguard are not brokers of choice for options.  Vanguard discourages trading, in particular by raising the commission as you place more trades, well, at least from the last time I looked at their commission schedule.  I don't know if that has changed with the recent wave of commission elimination.  For options, in no particular order, take a look at tastyworks, ThinkOrSwim and Interactive Brokers.

Comment: @Bob I was under the impression that if they fill your order off-exchange they are required to match or beat the current exchange bid (for sells) or ask (for buys), which means you don't get a poorer price. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JB Chouinard - There's limited information available about the inner workings of Payment For Order Flow.  Everything that I've read indicates that there are issues with it and the general consensus is that yes, they have to give you NBBO but if you are routed to an exchange with limited liquidity, NBBO may change by the time your order gets rerouted elsewhere.  In addition, PFOF routers like Robinhood are not likely to be sharing maker/taker fees. That's no big deal for an investor but definitely is for a trader.

Comment: @Bob  Interesting, thanks. It also occurred to me after making he comment, that, obviously, the exchange doesn't necessarily give you best execution, so beating the exchange is not a guarantee of getting the best price. The counterfactual to PFOF is probably a *different* market maker who beats the exchange by a wider margin, not the exchange itself.